# ¿ Como puedo hacer este casteo de un adaptador que puede ser null a la clase no null?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

```
companion object {
var  contactos:ArrayList<Contacto>? = null
var adaptador:AdaptadorCustom? = null

fun agregarContacto(contacto:Contacto)
{
    contactos?.add(contacto)
}
fun obtenerContactos(index:Int):Contacto{
    return adaptador?.getItem(index) as Contacto
}
fun eliminarContacto(index: Int)
{
    contactos?.removeAt(index)
}
fun actualizarContacto(index:Int,nuevoContacto:Contacto){
    contactos?.set(index,nuevoContacto)
}
```

}

Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.contactos/com.example.contactos.Detalle}: kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type com.example.contact Lo que hace es castear el adaptador a la data class Contactos

Comment: Agrega el código de tu activity y de tu adapter por favor, indicando la línea de código dónde el logcat te marca error "FatalException... at com.example.Activity..."

Comment: Gracias amigo por su comentairio, pero la app ya funciona, creo que era un problema con las actualizaciones.